# Compiler warnings and -(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)iInvocation

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings, message-forwarding

I have a class which is mostly delegating its method implementations to a member variable.

To simplify writing it I implemented

```
-(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)iInvocation;
```

and

```
-(NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
```

This enabled my class to implement a few protocols without a large amount of boilerplate code.

It is working pretty well, except that the compiler is throwing warnings for all the methods I am not implementing, which are actually forwarded to the member variable.
Is there a way for me to tell the system that those methods are in fact implemented, or to shut up just those warnings for just that source?

The compiler is emitting 3 kinds of warnings:

1. Method in Protocol not implemented
2. Property XXX requires method XXX
3. to be implemented Incomplete implementation

In the code bellow the class of the object I delegate to is `ShareUser` and the instance is `_user`

```
-(void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)iInvocation
{
    SEL aSelector = [iInvocation selector];
    if ([ShareUser instancesRespondToSelector:aSelector])
        [iInvocation invokeWithTarget:_user];
    else
        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:aSelector];
}
-(NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ([ShareUser instancesRespondToSelector:aSelector])
        return [ShareUser instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding compiler warnings when doing message forwarding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259012/avoiding-compiler-warnings-when-doing-message-forwarding)

Comment: Although related (and I had not found this question in my previous search) this is not the same issue.  In my case the forwarding class implements a protocol and all calls are to the protocol methods so there is no warning when invoking the method.  The problem is that when my class is compiled I have many warnings.  I have updated the original post to show the warnings